# Google+ API with youtube-api-v3

Tags: javascript, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the channel profile image or user profile image on videoId from youtube-api-v3. How do I query that?

**UPDATE**
also using the channelId as search query is acceptable. Just tell me where to find the profile image of channel or user. It's easy to manipulate the json if I know where to find the image.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you read the YouTube API docs?  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, try to query some snippets using google apis explorer, when I explore the json there is no profile image, I just want to get profile image

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. So I'll post how to get for others who get on this post.

Because youtube is connected with google+ and users from google+ can use youtube at full service. Also channels on youtubes are connected and we all know that google "One account for all of google." So here is how you get a profile image.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Thats all, Sorry for my bad expression on question :)